# pagesize=0 on /search throwing error

Tags: bug, status-completed

http://api.stackapps.com/0.9/search?intitle=a&pagesize=0

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 4001,
    "message": "The 'pagesize' query parameter is invalid."
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed.